# Grep and replace the character from grepped result

Tags: sed, grep

I am trying to grep the line from file and then from $1 I am trying to change the character.
eg

```
cat file1.txt
Surjit
Shilpa
cchiku
end of file
```

I tried and grepped the line which start with s.

```
grep -e "S"
```

Then I want to replace the 4th character to x for all grepped result in the file1.txt

I tried

```
sed -i "s/./x/4" file1.txt
```

How can I do this only for grepped results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sed '/pattern/s/find/replace/' file` syntax:

```
sed '/^S/s/./x/4' file
#     ^^ ^^^^^^^
#     |  replace the 4th character with x
#     |
#     on lines starting with S
```

With your file:

```
$ sed '/^S/s/./x/4' file
Surxit
Shixpa
cchiku
end of file
```

Note I am using `/^S/` as a pattern to match lines *starting* with S, because if you just say `/S/` it will match any line *containing* S. The anchor `^` indicates the beginning of the line.

Comment: It works.  If I am using pattern and grepping some $1 from line then will it work?
I cant use grep -e "regxp" | sed something

Comment: @Raj of course, just say `sed "/$1/s/./x/4" file` or place it in a var `var=$1` and then `sed "/$var/s/./x/4" file`

Comment: And of course, you can avoid the unnecessary use of `grep` by using something like `sed -n -e '/^S/s/./x/4p'` to print only the lines that were matched by the initial pattern.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [fedorqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38975208/171318) is to include the *starting with `S`* condition into the pattern itself:

```
sed 's/^\(S..\)./\1x/' file
```

The command matches lines starting with `S` and puts the `S` and the following two characters into a matching group. In the replacement part the content of the matching group will get reused and next character after it will get replaced by `x`.

Comment: Nice one! I am curious and what is best internally: to perform the search separately and then the replacement (as I did) or to match in the matching part as you did.

Comment: I guess it depends on the input data, but let's give it a short try! :) .... minute ...

Comment: @fedorqui I just did a short test: cat the above input file with itself until we've a file with 200 million lines. Your solution took 1:59 minutes, my took 1:17 minutes. Actually that makes sense.

Comment: How funny, I would've guessed the opposite, since your regex seems to be more expensive, so more time to compute. Thanks for the comparison!

Comment: @fedorqui Actually the regex is not so complicated. But I also thing the complexity of the regex(es) is the key here. Of course in combination with the input data

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v FS="" -v OFS="" '/^S/{$4="x"}1' infile
Surxit
Shixpa
cchiku
end of file
```